# Solution with several project namespaces

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

i am now developing a c# solution with 5 projects.

When i created the project under the solution, each project has its own namespace. My question is should i unify the namespaces using the solution namespace to avoid any scope problems later ?

Besides, i have a project for the Win Forms and using folders under it (to organize the forms). Each folder has several form.

When i want to use the form, i found that i have to mention the folder also.

What should i do then ?

Comment: Folder have nothing to do with your problem in calling the forms, probably, this is because that when you create an object in visual studio, by default it creates a name space for that object that is the same as the folder name that it was created in, you can change it after the creation, it is just a default behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Namespace is not related to the project structure but it is good habit follow the project structure. This make orientation in code much better. There is no need to unify namespace from scope reason. It should mirror your logical project layout. eg. your namespace can start with company (or product) name and than follow with component and then follow with your structure:

```
MyProduct.DataLayer
MyProduct.UI
MyProduct.Tools
MyProduct
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how is it with the folders under the project. the same ?

Comment: Namespaces in the project should mirror your folder structure but it is not mandatory. If you use same logic in the namespace and folder naming it will help you orientate in the project.